# How to add a compiler flag to only one target in Podfile?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, compiler-flags, podfile

I have a podfile setup as below and I would like to install a compiler flag to a dependency which is installed for both "Target1" and "Target2". My problem is that I only want to install it for "Target1" dependency but not for "Target2". I tried to add in the post install but it's adding to both targets. Would something like that be possible somehow?

```
source "https://cdn.cocoapods.org/"

use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '13.0'
minimum_deployment_target = 13.0

abstract_target 'MyApp' do

  pod 'SwiftLint', '~> 0.27.0'

  target 'Target1' do
    pod 'Target1Pod', :path => '../target-1/'
  end

  target 'Target2' do
    pod 'Target2Pod', :path => '../target-2/'
  end
end
```

My post_install trial:

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pod_targets.each do |t|
    if t.name == "Target1"
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |targ|
        if targ.to_s == "Dependency"
          targ.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS'] << 'MY_COMPILER_FLAG'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparently it does not work using the Podfile because you have multiple targets sharing the same dependency, therefore it will always share the compiler flag you pass as well. The solution I found is using the Podspecs.

I the shared dependencys' Podspec I added two subspecs (also important as otherwise it will take the one you add by default)

```
  s.default_subspec = "Default"

  s.subspec "Default" do |d|
  end

  s.subspec "MYSUBSPEC" do |mysubspec|
    mysubspec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => '$(inherited) -D MY_COMPILER_FLAG'
    }
  end
```

On the target's podspec you have to add this and this way it will only install to the target you want to:

```
s.dependency 'MyDependency/MYSUBSPEC'
```